# Ctrl+z java application

Tags: java

I'm trying to catch the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> hotkey in my java app but for some reason it doesn't work. Os used `Linux`. I didn't try on other OS. This is my code:

```
undo = new AbstractAction("Undo") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               System.out.println("undo");
            }
        };
textComponent.getInputMap().put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()),
                RightClicItems.UNDO);

textComponent.getActionMap().put(RightClicItems.UNDO, undo);
```